# VS Code open file in new tab hotkey

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to navigate VS Code with only the keyboard. I want to select a file in the explorer, then use a hotkey to open in new tab.

Space and Enter replace the existing tab. This because I have preview mode enabled. I often do want to replace the current tab instead of opening a new one. I want to be able to choose between opening in a new tab and replacing the current tab by hotkey.

Control + Enter opens a file in a new column. Often I want to open the file in an existing column, but a new tab. How do I do that with explorer-friendly hotkeys?

Comment: if you double click on a file in the explorer it opens in the same column (no preview), I did not find a shortcut for this action, or a command similar to `explorer.openToSide`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a selected file in a new tab you can do `ctrl+K O`(first press `ctrl+k` then press `O`).You can do `ctrl+K ctrl+S` to open Keyboard Shortcuts. Some of them does not have keyboard shortcuts by default. In there you can assign your keyboard shortcut for the action you desire.